# Invalid attempt to access a field before calling Read() vb.net

Tags: vb.net

I Got this error not because of code error but because of there is no data in my table

How to check if there is no data and return in variable as 0

here is my code
i am trying to get counter number, but it's error when no records

```
Public Function GetCount()
   Dim count As Integer
   Dim cmd As New MySqlCommand
   Dim reader As MySqlDataReader = Nothing
   Conn.OpenConn()
   Dim sqlstr As String
   sqlstr = "SELECT counter FROM st_sales ORDER BY salesid DESC LIMIT 1"
   Try
    'CREATE COMMAND
     cmd = New MySqlCommand(sqlstr, Conn.Conn)

     reader = cmd.ExecuteReader()
     If reader.Read() Then
        count = reader.GetInt32(0) + 1
     Else
        MsgBox("Error")
     End If
    Finally
       reader.Close()
       Conn.CloseConn()
    End Try
    Return count
End Function
```

Thanks for any healp

Comment: pls share some code - we cannot possible know what you are trying. For example I guess you want to read some table/row - but what kind?

Comment: can you post the line where you get an exception and the exception too? as it is this should not call `.GetInt32` if there are no rows (`reader.Read()` will return `false` in this case)

Comment: I would change your query to give you the sum of the counters... For example: SELECT SUM(counter) FROM st_sales, BAM no need for a variable and checking if the reader has rows or not...

Comment: Also on another note, it's a very good practice to wrap your connections/commands in a using statement to ensure that these get released properly...just a thought :)

Comment: I am not trying to sum the counter but i wanna do increment based on date, e.g the date is 2014-09-04, then it will count + 1 , then when it is 2014-09-05 then the counter is set to 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
If reader.HasRows then
 'do the counting
else
  count=0
end if
```